# Python's lambda followed by a class?

Tags: python, class, lambda

What does the following code do?

```
network_optimizer_ctor=lambda: hrl.network.LocalOptimizer(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3), grad_clip=10.0),
```

here hrl.network.LocalOptimizer is a class name

Comment: What are you trying to create tho

Answer (score 0):

After running that code, `network_optimizer_ctor` will be a function which accepts no arguments and returns what I'm assuming is an optimization method available through tensorflow. I'm also assuming you pulled that either from a function definition or where you were calling some function? Based on your spacing, it seems like `network_optimizer_ctor` is being used as a keyword argument or a default value.

As a simpler example, consider the following code, where the only thing that changed was the return value.

```
>>> network_optimizer_ctor = lambda: 'Hello World!'

>>> print network_optimizer_ctor
<function <lambda> at 0x781b8a62dc80>

>>> print network_optimizer_ctor()
Hello World!
```